# CodeIgniter routing for security

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing

In my `CI application`, I have used fake URLs for my form submit action attributes. CI router will take care to map those virtual URls to actual physical URLs. Does this really a good practice in security wise?

In the same manner, I 'm hiding my `.json` data store file path.

Please, let me know about if you have any suggestions. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This won't really make any difference as it is easy enough to see the "fake url" and Codeigniter is always going to redirect to the correct one. The easiest way to think of routes is as a nicknames and nothing more.

The security comes with the validation of the data, and possible user permissions depending on your application.